# Saving data from firebase storage to view it later within my application in android studio

Tags: android, video, firebase-storage, offline, raw

can anyone help with how I can achieve the saving of videos from firebase storage to my android app and then view them later from my application even if I have lost internet connection. However, I do not want them to appear in the gallery, I just want my videos to be accessible using my application.

I can access videos that I put locally into my raw folder and I am wondering if I can save videos from firebase into the raw folder for future opening. I f it is possible, please help me as to how i can do that.